# Binding and Displaying Data With Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I am new to Aurelia. I have a WebApi that will return some data that I would like to populate into my exported model and then display the info on the screen.I'm thinking it would go into my run event but am not sure. Can anybody tell me how to do this . Any information would be most appreciated. My code is below.

--Jason

```html
import 'fetch';
import {HttpClient, json} from 'aurelia-fetch-client';
import {inject} from 'aurelia-dependency-injection';

declare var window: { wcApiUrl: string, wcAmtInstanceId: string };

@inject(HttpClient)
export class BureauModUpdate {

    files: string;
    
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        http.configure(x => {
            x.defaults.headers = { 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + window.wcAmtInstanceId }
        });
    }

    public run(): void {
        //Would I put it here ??

    }
     upload(): void {
         var form = new FormData()
         for (var i = 0; i <= this.files.length; i++) {
             form.append('file', this.files[i])
             this.http.fetch(window.wcApiUrl + '/Lookup/BureauModUpdate/CreateBureauModUpdates', {
                 method: 'post',
                 body: form
             })
         }

   

    }
}

export class BureauModUpdateHistory  {
    public IndexId: number;
    public UploadID:number;
    public EmployeeNum: number;
    public filename: string;
    public Bureau: string;
    public UploadedDate: Date;
    public UploadedStatus: string;
    public ErrorInfo: string;
    public RecordCount: number;
  
}
```

Comment: It would be worth your timeto read through the docs on Aurelia HTTP services: http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/fetch-client/latest/http-services/1

Comment: It completely depends on what you want to do: trigger the request on user event? Or on VM activation? Or on component attachement?

Comment: Trying to perform a get as soon as the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

To make something happen when the page loads, use the `attached()` Aurelia component lifecycle method, like this:

```
attached() {
  // do something here
}
```

For more information on the Component Lifecycle, see the documentation on [Aurelia's DocHub](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/creating-components/3).

**Example using Fetch to get data:**

For getting HTTP data using fetch (or any other web service), you need to use an async call (using `.then` to chain the next event).  For example:

```
this.http.fetch(url).then(response => {
  this.data = response;
}
```

Then, just bind your data to `this.data` (depending on what type of data you're getting).  For example:

```
<template>
  Hello, ${data.fname}!
</template>
```

Comment: The upload works fine. Not the issue. I am simply trying to make another Webapi call to populate BureauModUpdateHistoryclass and then display the info when the page loads. So I'm thinking it would be something like the run() which makes a very similar api call... public run(): void {
        this.http.fetch(window.wcApiUrl + '/Lookup/BureauModUpdate/GetLatestBureauModUpdate', {
            method: 'get',
            
        })

Comment: The point of my post was not so much about the upload() routine -- it was to show you that anything that you want to run when the page loads should be placed in the `attached()` method.  I'll update my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: Ok thank you. Knocking on the door now. So now I have a class (BureauModUpdateHistory) to which I am trying to bind the response to. Much like you showed with this.data. But now its telling me Type 'Response' is not assignable to my class. What is it that I need to do?

Comment: What is the format of the data you're receiving from your http fetch call? You can add a `console.log(response);` in the `.then()` function to examine it.

Comment: Were you able to get this working?  Was my answer helpful?